# AngularJS Directive integrating bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a bootstrap tooltip which isnt rendering within my NG-repeat from my research I see the tooltip wont render on angular driven content and a directive should be created to handle this issue to establish it.

If I have an existing directive relating to this ng-repeat is it possible to include this in the existing directive?

From another stackoverflow article I took on board their tooltip function and tried to apply it to my existing directive but it isn't working:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module("tpAccStatus")
    .directive(["tpAccStatusTransactionRow", tpAccStatusTransactionRow], ["tooltip", tooltip]);

function tpAccStatusTransactionRow() {
    return {
        scope: {
            trans: "=tpAccStatusTransactionRow",
            accountNumber: "=",
            setMessageState: '&'
        },
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "tpAccStatusTransactionRow.directive.html",
        bindToController: true,
        controller: "tpAccStatusTransactionRowCtrl",
        controllerAs: "transCtrl"
    };
}

function tooltip() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).hover(function () {
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function () {
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
}

})();
```

Within my directive template I then reference:

```
<td><span tooltip data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Select an Account"><span class="fa fa-sort fa-fw"></span></span></td>
```

Thanks